# Ajax post works on localhost, but not on nginx server

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, post, nginx

I was experimenting with building a small CMS for a project. Part of it was, that when you click on the `save-button` your current edits will be saved.

```js
$('.save-button').click(function() {

  var speisekarte_content = $(".speisekarte-content").html();
  console.log(speisekarte_content);
  var ajaxurl = 'save.php',
    data = {
      'content': speisekarte_content
    };
  $.post(ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
    alert("action performed successfully");
  });

});
```

The save.php looks like this:

```php
<?php

$post_data = $_POST['content'];

if (function_exists('fopen')) { 
    if (!empty($post_data)) {
        $filename = 'speisekarte-content.php';
        $handle = fopen($filename, "w");
        fwrite($handle, $post_data);
        fclose($handle);
        echo $file;
    }
};

?>
```

So it basically just adds the content that should be saved to a file called `speisekarte-content.php` … This worked perfectly on localhost – until I uploaded it to my nginx server and it stopped working as supposed. 
This is the error log that I found in the javascript console:

```
POST
http://www.myurl.com/editable/save.php net::ERR_TIMED_OUT

k.cors.a.crossDomain.send @ jquery.min.js:4
n.extend.ajax @ jquery.min.js:4
n.(anonymous function) @ jquery.min.js:4
(anonymous function) @ main.js:99
```

The nginx error logs are the following

```
2015/06/22 08:43:45 [error] 6804#0: *63817 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Notice:  Undefined index: content in /var/www/myurl.com/html/editable/save.php on line 2
PHP message: PHP Warning:  fopen(autosave.php): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/myurl.com/html/editable/save.php on line 27
PHP message: PHP Warning:  fwrite() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /var/www/myurl.com/html/editable/save.php on line 28
PHP message: PHP Warning:  fclose() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /var/www/myurl.com/html/editable/save.php on line 29
PHP message: PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: file in /var/www/myurl.com/html/editable/save.php on line 30" while reading response header from upstream, client: 176.0.1.54, server: myurl.com, request: "POST /editable/save.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock:", host: "www.myurl.com", referrer: "http://www.myurl.com/editable/"
```

Is this related to nginx or my code?

Comment: What does the `console` has to say?

Comment: @Daan It allows to set two variables in a row. Retador, have you check file permissions, htacess, etc ?

Comment: @Tushar  I posted the error log up there … otherwise it logs the content of my div with the class `speisekarte-content` :)

Comment: have you looked at the error log on the server?

Comment: @VilleneuveMichaël  No, what would I have to check in htacess? I'm a noob, sorry :)

Comment: I don't know, it might be blocking some requests, or on the remote server, file might not be readable or something like that, could you give us the content ?

Comment: @Augwa  I just added the server error logs to my question :)

Comment: The idea with an error log is that **you have to actually read it**. Look at the first error message in the nginx log, read it, understand it. Then fix the permissions! Then error 1, 2 and 3 will go away. Then start looking at error 4.

Comment: The problem is in your error log, you have permission issues.

Comment: RE: _This worked perfectly on localhost_ I bet if you look at the error logs on your localhost system you will see a lots of errors in there are well. When testing on localhost you need to have all possible error report turned on, otherwise its not testing code, its just testing how good your _blindfold_ is

Comment: @RiggsFolly The problem with the error log is that I have to understand it. If I don't understand it, I can't fix anything… As a newbie to server-side programming all these logs are pretty cryptic :)

Comment: If the **first error message** in the nginx log is to cryptic for you, then I have to say I think you are in **totally the wrong job**. It should at least give you a clue what to do a google search for!

Comment: @RiggsFolly It's not my job, so chill ;)

Answer (score 0):

Your log say that your application don't have the right to write in his current emplacement.
Your should check the right on your file
can you post the output of a `ls -al` in your app's folder ?

Comment: Ok, I put the output in a piratepad file: http://piratepad.net/ep/pad/view/ro.tHwqX$uuO1T/latest

Comment: All your files belong to root, so i guess the folder containing it to. 
Nginx can't create file if the owner is root, you have to change the owner or the group of the folder containing your app

Comment: oh ok … and to which owner should I change it? just a random one? I thought root would be the "super-user" which can perform basically any action

Comment: you should change it to your nginx user (don't exactly know wich one it is for nginx)
root is a super user who can perform anything but those files are owned by root, so you can't perform action on it